# Find C of $Cx^{a-1}y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}$ for $0<x<1$ $0<y<1$ and $0<y<1-x<1$

Tags: statistics

Find C of  $Cx^{a-1}y^{b-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}$ for $0<x<1$ $0<y<1$ and $0<y<1-x<1$. So I have so show that $C=\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}$. I have the following integral but I'm stuck and just really need a hint about how to start integration:

$C\int_{0}^{1}y^{b-1}\int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}dxdy$

Comment: can you fix the formating a bit?

Comment: Do you know (can you use) the value of $$\int_0^1t^{u-1}(1-t)^{v-1}\,\mathrm dt\ ?$$

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out how to get that first integral to be of that form above. The (1-x-y) is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable $(x,y)=((1-y)z,y)$ yields the Jacobian $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=(1-y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$ on the range $0\lt z\lt1$ and the identity $1-x-y=(1-y)(1-z)$, hence $$I=\int_{0}^{1}y^{b-1}\int_{0}^{1-y} x^{a-1}(1-x-y)^{c-1}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$ is also $$I=\int_{0}^{1}y^{b-1}\int_{0}^{1} (1-y)^{a-1}z^{a-1}(1-z)^{c-1}(1-y)^{c-1}(1-y)\mathrm dz\mathrm dy,$$ that is, $$I=\int_{0}^{1}y^{b-1}(1-y)^{a+c-1}\mathrm dy\cdot\int_{0}^{1}z^{a-1}(1-z)^{c-1}\mathrm dz,$$ and, then, the classical Beta identity yields $$I=\mathrm{B}(b,a+c)\cdot\mathrm{B}(a,c)=\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(a+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+c)}=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}.$$